# Finding all the possible combinations of a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, counter, pandas-groupby

I have a data like this:

```
     Price  Web  Destinations  Airport  Flight  Afterflight  Global
0      1    1             0        0       0            0       0
1      1    1             1        1       1            1       1
2      1    1             1        1       0            1       1
3      0    1             0        0       0            0       0
4      0    0             0        0       0            0       0
```

and I would like to find all the possible combinations of the variables except Global and count the number of instances of each combination. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: have you tried anything so far, can you post the desired output ?

Comment: I would like to be something like : 1 1 1 1 1 1 number:43  1 1 1 1 0 0 number : 21, like a Truth Table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` + `size`:

```
res = df.groupby(df.columns[:-1].tolist()).size().rename('Count').reset_index()

print(res)

   Price  Web  Destinations  Airport  Flight  Afterflight  Count
0      0    0             0        0       0            0      1
1      0    1             0        0       0            0      1
2      1    1             0        0       0            0      1
3      1    1             1        1       0            1      1
4      1    1             1        1       1            1      1
```

Your example isn't interesting because all combinations are unique.

Comment: What about `list(itertools.combinations(df['colname'], 2))`

Comment: @pygo, Possibly, but I like (if I know how) to stick with the Pandas way, since it's more geared towards working with NumPy.

Comment: @jpp It actually works very well and does exactly what I want. Thanks guys

Comment: @TKir, If this worked, please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (green tick on left) so other users know.